# csv string in url with angular ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to work with a list of ids in a param in the url.

I defined a var in the url:

url: "/{arrayOfNames}/",

When I click on a link that was generated by ui-sref="{arrayOfNames : '1'}" it directs to to "/1/".
What I need to do is to concat a string to it instead of replacing current one, so I'll have "/1,2,3/" i.e. and of course handle corner cases.

I tried doing:
ui-sref="{arrayOfNames : arrayOfNames + ',2'}" but that doesn't work.

What is the best approach to implement this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work as of 0.2.13:

```
url: "/{arrayOfNames}/",
params: { arrayOfNames: { array: true } }
```

Alternate form:

```
url: "/{arrayOfNames[]}/"
```

Then $stateParams["arrayOfNames[]"] should be an array.